# Depth of a PostgreSQL function

Tags: postgresql, depth, stored-functions

How can i know the depth of a stored procedure (they are called function in postgresql), that function calls two other recursive function ?
Is it possible to know many time that function was called.
The reason why i want to do that is because i would like to switch to an iterative approach rather than a recursive which is more efficient in my understanding.

The first function is below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.generategrid(parameters)
 RETURNS SETOF text AS
$BODY$

DECLARE
      /* input params */

BEGIN
      execute generaterowandcols(parameters)
END;

$BODY$
```

And as a mentioned above it calls another function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.generaterowandcols(parameters)
$BODY$

DECLARE
      /* input params */

BEGIN
      execute generaterow(parameters)

      execute generaterowandcols(parameters)
END;

$BODY$
```

And the function that is before calls the fucntion below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.generaterow(parameters)
$BODY$

DECLARE
      /* input params */

BEGIN
      execute generaterow(parameters)

END;

$BODY$
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to know that? What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve with that?

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Legal syntax instead of pseudocode would be much more useful. You seem to have working functions - I assume plpgsql? And you forgot to declare your version of Postgres.

Comment: Yes you are right plpgsql and the version is 9.6

Answer (score 0):

Use [`GET STACKED DIAGNOSIS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CALL-STACK) to get `PG_CONTEXT` which contains the call stack.

Answer (score -1):

Using the pg_trigger_depth() built in function... 
... But this is for trigger function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func() RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
    IF pg_trigger_depth() <> 1 THEN
        RAISE NOTICE pg_trigger_depth();
    END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```